# Failing to regenerate report: ReportProcessingException on rendering extension

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I can generate a report in SSRS 2008 but when I try to generate it again it will fail with exception below. It will however work again once after SSRS is restarted. What configuration option could be affecting this? (I have added all necessary extensions.)

> processing!ReportServer_0-1!1ef4!01/28/2013-16:39:41::
>
> ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report server or it is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services., ;
>
> INFO: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report server or it is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.
>   library!ReportServer_0-1!1ef4!01/28/2013-16:39:41::
>
> WARN: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report server or it is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateRenderer(String format, IRenderingExtension& newRenderer)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderSnapshot(RenderingContext rc, ProcessingContext pc, GetResource getResourceCallback)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RenderFromSnapshot.DoRendering(ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RenderFromSnapshot.CallProcessingAndRendering(ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, OnDemandProcessingResult& result)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RenderStrategyBase.ExecuteStrategy(OnDemandProcessingResult& processingResult)

Comment: http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/ForumTopic.aspx?lang=en&topic_id=2264&forum_id=56

Answer (score 1):

It seems SSRS is trying to load an assembly containing some report rendering functionality (maybe some charts you added)?

If this is the case, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769) article explains how to register a DLL with SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the problem was SQL Web Edition does not support html extensions. You need at least Standard. Why it worked once remains the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in our case is that via API we were requesting a report and attempting to convert the report from HTML to a different rendering extension. And, unfortunately, the specific Reporting Services instance’s configuration file has not been configured\extended to support the requested rendering format.

In MS SQL Server 2008-R2, the configuration file is located in a directory structure resembling the following:

```
 E:
   \Program Files
      \Microsoft SQL Server
         \MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER_RS
            \Reporting Services
               \ReportServer
```

And, the actual file name is rsreportserver.config

In the configuration file, find the “Render” section:

< Configuration >

< Extensions >

< Render >

Within the Render section, find the corresponding “Extension” entry.
If the extension is not found, add it: